# How to clear my notification badge

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, push-notification, pushbots

I have a app to which i can send push notifications using pushbots. The user is able to receive the notification and on clicking it he/she can open the app. However the badge notification still shows that there is a notification. How would i set my notification badge to 0.

This is my appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Register for Remote Notifications
    [Pushbots sharedInstanceWithAppId:@"5503e09a1d0ab1481f8b45a1"];
    NSDictionary * userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if(userInfo) {
        // Notification Message
        NSString* notificationMsg = [userInfo valueForKey:@"alert"];
        // Custom Field
        NSString* title = [userInfo valueForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"Notification Msg is %@ and Custom field title = %@", notificationMsg , title);
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)onReceivePushNotification:(NSDictionary *) pushDict andPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload {
    NSString* message = [pushDict valueForKey:@"alert"];
    UIAlertView *alertMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Event !" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Open" otherButtonTitles: @"I will check later",nil];
    [alertMessage show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    Pushbots * pushbots = [Pushbots sharedInstance];
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Open"]) {
        [pushbots OpenedNotification];
    }
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call this in your application :

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Obviously this needs a little more work. If you're dealing with messages for example, you'd need to decrement the badge number by the number of messages read and make sure to not go below zero.

You can also use the `"badge"` key to modify the current badge through the notification payload itself.

for example use 
`{..., "badge" : "increment", ...}`

or

`{...,"badge" : 3, ...}`

The first one would be the most frequent version i'm guessing.

But if your app is fairly simple, then just call this and your badge will be set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to update your pushbots lib to 1.1 and use the following method which will clear the badge locally and on the server:

```
[[Pushbots sharedInstance] clearBadgeCount];
```

Comment: This is the right answer because it clears the count on the server. On Swift, use this didFinishLaunchingWithOptions on the AppDelegate.app: Pushbots.sharedInstance().clearBadgeCount();

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    Pushbots.sharedInstance().clearBadgeCount()
    }

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication)
    {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.  
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    Pushbots.sharedInstance().clearBadgeCount()
    }
```

**Objective C**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
     {
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
     [[Pushbots sharedInstance] clearBadgeCount];
     }

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application 
     {
      // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

      [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
      [[Pushbots sharedInstance] clearBadgeCount];
      }
```